# I recently create a grade calculator by JavaScript but the script is not working

Tags: javascript

I recently created a grade calculator using JavaScript... but the script is not working!

the problem is.. when I enter a number like "55" the result is showing in three dialouge box one is saying " you got A+ " second is " you got A" and showing all the grades i add into the code

the following code is

```
var name= prompt("Enter your name");

var number= prompt("Enter your number");

alert("Hello , " + name);

if ( number >= 80 ); {

alert("Hello you got A+");

} 

if ( number >= 70 ); {

alert("Hello you have got A");

}

 if ( number >= 60 ); { 

alert("Hello you have got A-");

 } if (number >= 50 );  { 

alert("Hello you have got B"); }
```

can any one help me? whats wrong ? really sorry for my bad english!!

Comment: We might be able to help you if you describe what the problem is. *"It is not working"* is not a problem/error description.

Comment: By "not working" do you mean there are no alert boxes shown or that there are a lot of them?

Comment: no, they are not showing any boxes so that i can know which grade i get

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be placing `;` after your if statements. Remove them.

```
if (number >= 50 ); {
                  ^
```

Also, I'm guessing that you only want one of those statements to run depending on the number entered? You could try using `else if's` if you only want one of those statements to run. Also, use `parseInt()` on your number prompt.

[**Here's a working jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LYRN7/1/).

---

```
var name= prompt("Enter your name");   
var number= parseInt(prompt("Enter your number"));
alert("Hello , " + name);

if (number >= 80) {    
  alert("Hello you got A+");    
} 

else if ( number >= 70) {    
  alert("Hello you have got A");    
}

else if ( number >= 60) {     
  alert("Hello you have got A-");    
} 

else if (number >= 50) {    
  alert("Hello you have got B"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For calculating correct grade you should change your code as changing condition as following:

```
var name= prompt("Enter your name");

var number= prompt("Enter your number");
alert("Hello , " + name);
if ( number >= 80 ) {
alert("Hello you got A+");
}
if ( number >= 70 && number < 80) {
alert("Hello you have got A");
}
if ( number >= 60  && number < 70 ) { 
alert("Hello you have got A-");
} if(number >= 50  && number < 60)  { 
alert("Hello you have got B"); }
```

Comment: A link (and it's not even a link) alone is useless. Add the code here and explain the changes you made and why.

Comment: @FelixKling : Hey thanks for guide. Next time i will remember.

Comment: You can [**edit** your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16277546/edit) and do it now! ;)

Answer (score 0):

The number needs to be parsed into integer before using. By default it is string.

```
  var number= parseInt(prompt("Enter your number"));
```

Then on all if statements you are having ";". Remove them. The code will work fine.

```
    window.onload = function() {
     var name= prompt("Enter your name");

     var number= parseInt(prompt("Enter your number"));

      alert("Hello , " + name);

      if ( number >= 80 ) {

       alert("Hello you got A+");

       } 

       if ( number >= 70 ) {

      alert("Hello you have got A");

            }

       if ( number >= 60 ) { 

      alert("Hello you have got A-");

        } if (number >= 50 )  { 

      alert("Hello you have got B"); }
       }
```

Comment: Welcome anytime. If it works please accept the comment as answer.

Answer (score 0):

try using "else if" instead of just "if" for the alternative options. If the score is larger than the first option it will also be larger than all of the others so if will return "true" for all cases. In addition as stated by Zenith remove the ; after the "if" conditions and ideally use parseInt() to ensure that you are comparing numbers as suggested by Kirubhananth Chellam.

```
var name= prompt("Enter your name");

var number= prompt("Enter your number");

alert("Hello , " + name);

if ( number >= 80 ) {

    alert("Hello you got A+");

} 

else if ( number >= 70 ) {

    alert("Hello you have got A");

}

else if ( number >= 60 ) { 

    alert("Hello you have got A-");

}

else if (number >= 50 )  { 

    alert("Hello you have got B"); 
}
```